# Google app engine MySql connection timeouts after 5 seconds

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine

I am debugging on my development server GAE application that uses push Queue to execute long stored proc. The task that execute the stored proc gets an exception:  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure.
The last packet successfully received from the server was 5,045 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 5,043 milliseconds ago.

How I can set the timeout to higher value?

Comment: would try those timeout values mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10772407/995891

Comment: Appy some markdown: Indent your pasted error message by 4 positions and separate it by a blank line from the rest.

Comment: Yeah, I tried a lot of things to no avail. Those 5 sec seems to be some Google app engine constrain.

Comment: Did you find any fix ?

Comment: no, I did not found the solution, just catch and ignore the exception. The SQL does the job anyway